# Strange variable overwrite in foreach loop

Tags: php, yii, foreach, sql-update

This must be something ugly obvious, but I'm stucked on this and can't solve it for past two hours.

I have this piece of code:

```
foreach($idMap as $menuId=>$pageId)
{
    echo('$this->update("menus_items", SET "link = /content/show?id='.$pageId.'" WHERE id = '.$menuId.');'."\n");

    $this->update
    (
        'menus_items',
        array('link'=>'/content/show?id='.$pageId),
        array('id = '.$menuId)
    );
}
```

`echo` part works as expected (`$pageId` is different for each item, taken from `$idMap`), while Yii's [`CDbCommand::update()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand/#update-detail) gets wako and have `$pageId` equal to it's last value for all loop iterations.

In other words, if I have 20 menu items and last item in result set has `pageId` = `18`, then when using `CDbCommand::update()`, I'm getting *all* menu items set to that last value.

There must be some variable overwriting here, but I can't find it for past two hours, especially, that `echo` put just one line above works great. Can someone help here.

Comment: we cannot see what `$this->update` does. I cannot see any overwriting. The error must be somewhere else.

Comment: What is `$this`? CActiveRecord?

Comment: @steven Thanks for attempting to help. It seems, that this problem must be somehow related to Yii. I'll ask at their forum. If I'll get some valuable answers there, I'll consider reposting them here. Thanks for double checking and assuring me, that I'm not missing something stupid.

Comment: @hamed As I wrote in my question, we're talking about `CDbCommand::update()`. Therefore, `$this` is `CDbCommand`, not `CActiveRecord`.

Answer (score 2):

Guessing, but does `$this->update()` expect a single array for its bind arguments?

```
$this->update
    (
        'menus_items',
        array(
            'link' => '/content/show?id='.$pageId,
            'id' => $menuId
        )
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for attempting to help. It seems, that this problem must be somehow related to Yii. I'll ask at their forum. If I'll get some valuable answers there, I'll consider reposting them here. Thanks for double checking and assuring me, that I'm not missing something stupid.