# CDbMigration::update does not work inside foreach loop

Tags: yii, sql-update, database-migration, yii-migrations

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29037370/1469208). There is something wrong, when using `CDbMigration::update()` inside `foreach` loop.

This code does not work correctly:

```
//This is executed inside Yii migration, so $this is CDbMigration.

foreach($idMap as $menuId=>$pageId)
{
    $this->update
    (
        'menus_items',
        array('link'=>'/content/show?id='.$pageId),
        array('id = '.$menuId)
    );
}
```

For each item in *$idMap* value of *$pageId* is always **the same** and equals value of **last item** in *$idMap* array. Therefore, every menu item points to the same URL.

This code works like a charm:

```
foreach($idMap as $menuId=>$pageId)
{
    $sql = "UPDATE `menus_items` SET link = '/content/show?id=".$pageId."' WHERE id = ".$menuId."; ";

    Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
}
```

For each item in *$idMap* value of *$pageId* is always **different** and equals value of **current item** in *$idMap* array. Therefore, every menu item points to correct URL.

The same goes, when executing all statements in one SQL query:

```
$sql = '';

foreach($idMap as $menuId=>$pageId)
{
    $sql .= "UPDATE `menus_items` SET link = '/content/show?id=".$pageId."' WHERE id = ".$menuId."; ";
}

Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```

Again, everything is OK.

Why using `CDbMigration::update()` fails, while direct SQL execution works like a charm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are providing the criteria parameter properly @ `array('id = '.$menuId)`
. You should use a string if you want to send it like that, putting it in an array presumes you are mapping out the conditions in a key => value pair. Also you should be wrapping the value constraint in quotes `id = "$menuId"`.